# OpenOffice Calc (Macros)

Tags: loops, openoffice-calc

I am trying to make a Loop in OpenOffice Calc (Macros)

I have tried this so far :

```
Sub Main 
    For x = 1 To 10 
        If Cells(x,1) = 50 Then
            Cells(x,1).Value = 20
        End If
    End For
End Sub
```

Does any one know how it works ?

Comment: You iterate through 10 cells and if their values is 50 you change that value to 20. Could you add more details about this? What do you want to know?

Comment: I get an Error (Syntax error )

Answer (score 0):

OpenOffice Basic (StarBasic) is not VBA. If your code should run from A1 to A10 in ActiveSheet, then in OO Basic it would be:

```
Sub Main

with ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
 for lRow = 0 to 9
  if .getCellByPosition(0, lRow).value = 50 then
   .getCellByPosition(0, lRow).value = 20
  endif
 next
end with

End Sub
```

Some links for beginners:
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Extensions_development_basic
there especially the XRAY tool is recommendable.

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide
there for your concrete problem:
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Cells_and_Ranges

Greetings

Axel